# Are the closed ordinals (apart from $0$ and $1$) precisely the regular cardinals?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, cardinals, order-theory, ordinals

Given a partially ordered set $P$, a **collection** of partially ordered sets, call it $\mathcal{Q}$, and an arbitrary function $f : P \rightarrow \mathcal{Q},$ we can form a new partially ordered set $\Sigma f$ as follows.

1. The elements of $\Sigma f$ are the pairs $(p,q) \in P \times \bigcup \mathcal{Q}$ such that $f(p) \ni q$.
2. Define $(p,q) \leq (p',q')$ iff either

   - $p < p'$ in the sense of $P$, or
   - $p=p',$ and letting $Q = f(p)=f(p'),$ we have that $q \leq q'$ in the sense of $Q$.

Note in particular that if $P$ is totally ordered and the elements of $\mathcal{Q}$ are totally ordered, then for all functions $f : P \rightarrow \mathcal{Q}$ we have that $\Sigma f$ is totally ordered. Similarly if 'totally ordered' is replaced by 'well-ordered.'

**Question 1**. Is there a standard name/notation for this construction? Where can I learn more?

Now call a collection $\mathcal{Q}$ of posets *closed* iff for all $P \in \mathcal{Q}$ and all $f : P \rightarrow \mathcal{Q}$ we have that $\Sigma f$ is order-isomorphic to an element of $\mathcal{Q}.$ Note also that an ordinal is not only a poset, but also collection of posets. Thus any given ordinal may or may not be closed. And since cardinals can be viewed as particular kinds of ordinals, any given cardinal may or may not be closed. <strike>In fact, it is easy to see that every infinite cardinal is closed.</strike>  (Thank you, Asaf, for your correction.) Furthermore, every regular cardinal is closed.

**Question 2.** Are the closed ordinals (apart from $0$ and $1$) precisely the regular cardinals?

Comment: So you really just replace every point in $P$ by a copy of $f(p)$. This is a sum of orders over $P$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, yes precisely. Is this technically called a 'sum of orders,' or did you just make that up?

Comment: I know that there *is* a term sum of orders, but I'm not 100% it full correlates to this definition if the orders are not well-orders (or scattered orders, or something).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your claim is wrong. It isn't true that cardinals are closed, it is true that regular cardinals are closed. In fact that gives an exact characterization of the closed ordinals.

First it is trivial that finite ordinals larger than $1$ are not closed. Now suppose that $\alpha+1$ is a successor ordinal, then $2\in\alpha+1$ and $\alpha\in\alpha+1$ then the map $f(0)=\alpha, f(1)=2$ witnesses that $\alpha+1$ is not closed.

We can generalize this to the case where $\delta$ is not a regular cardinal:

If $\delta$ is a limit ordinal and $\lambda=\operatorname{cf}(\delta)<\delta$ then we have:

1. $\lambda+1\in\delta$, we have $\{\delta_i\mid i<\lambda\}\subseteq\delta$ which is a cofinal sequence.
2. The map $f(i)=\delta_i$ for $i<\lambda$ and $f(\lambda)=1$ gives us an order type of $\delta+1\notin\delta$.

As for the name, I'm not familiar enough with order theory to answer that, but it seems that this is a generalized sum of orders, over $P$, I don't know for certain though.

Comment: Yes, you're quite right. My 'easy to see' claim is bogus.

Comment: I fixed the question. So my understanding so far is: every regular cardinal is closed, and you've shown that no singular cardinal is closed, and we're not yet sure whether there are ordinals which are closed, but which are non-cardinals. Right?

Comment: @user18921: No, I have shown that the only closed ordinals are regular cardinals. Non-cardinal ordinals are certainly not equal to their own cofinality.

Comment: Right, yes its making sense now.

Comment: Asaf, may I please edit your answer? I just want to rearrange some things to make it a bit clearer. Its up to you, of course.

Comment: @user18921: What things?

Comment: Well it would be better to put the statement 'But your claim is wrong. It is only true that regular cardinals are closed.' first. Then write the correct statement of the theorem. 'An ordinal is closed iff it is a regular cardinal, or 0 or 1.'

Comment: Right, that's better. Note that $0,1$ are regular cardinals in the sense that every cofinal subset has the same order type as $0,1$...

Comment: With regards to the 0 and 1 being regular cardinals - yes, I know, but I was under the impression that some authors exclude the finite cardinals. I actually feel slightly uncomfortable with this sort of thing in general - for instance, I'd prefer if $0$ and $\omega$ were viewed as inaccessible cardinals - but there's probably good reasons to exclude them that I'm not aware of yet. So I'll reserve judgement.

Comment: @user18921: $\omega$ is inaccessible. But when we usually say inaccessible we also mean countable, then it's obvious when we say "the existence of an inaccessible cardinal implies the consistency of $\sf ZFC$", something which is blatantly false for both $0$ and $\omega$. Finite cardinals are excluded because they are... well, finite. They have no room for manipulations like infinite ones have!